# Add the Custom drawer inside the Snippet View in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to add my custome drawer with some item inside the snippet view in eclipse by coding which will not be editable. i want to create plugine with that. Please help me for that. Please tell me which class i have to use to add my custom drawer inside the snippet view.

Thanks and Regards 
  Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Check the extension points in the Snippets view's plug-in.  It's made to do this.